# I want to distinguish b2Body

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I have a lot of bodies in World with Box2d.(B2Body) . I want to distinguish this Bodies.

For example I have

```
b2Body *ball;
b2Body *person1;
b2Body *person2;
b2Body *Person3;
```

which the person I want to hit the ball?

this b2body have **id** , **name** or other thing for distinguish?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `==` operator, for example:

```
void ContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
    b2Body *bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

    if ((bodyA == ball && bodyB == person1) || (bodyB == ball && bodyA == person1)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or you can also make use of `b2Body` user data (but you need to make sure all bodies are assigned the user data of the same class:

```
void ContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
    BodyUserData *bodyA_data = (BodyUserData *)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    BodyUserData *bodyB_data = (BodyUserData *)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    if ((bodyA_data.type == TYPE_BALL && bodyB_data == TYPE_PERSON1) || (bodyB_data.type == TYPE_BALL && bodyA_data == TYPE_PERSON1)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Lukman. it's correct.  ı added inside my code

this code->>>>>

```
- (void)beginContact:(b2Contact *)contact {

    b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();


    if ((bodyA == ball && bodyB == person1) || (bodyB == ball && bodyA == person1)) 
    {
        // do something

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"whine.wav"];


    }
}
```